# Dell G7 touchpad works sporadically

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

Sometimes I have to left click a dozen times to get response. It does not happen all of the time. Is there a fix? I am using a Dell G7 and Ubuntu 20.04.2. Gnome 3.36.8 Is it a Dell issue? a Ubuntu issue? a Gnome issue? or something else?